# Swift iOS. Multi line UILabel background color to follow the text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, background-color

I have a multi line UILabel which I want to set the background color exactly the same as when you highlight the text on a web browser with your mouse but cannot seem to find a solution.

This is what I got in my storyboard:
[image]

And this is what I am aiming to achieve:

[image]

This is the browser example I was mentioned above:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using attributed string

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                   initWithString:@"Some text line Some text line\nSome text line"];
[string addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
titleLabel.attributedText = string;
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
[Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-d) needed help to write swift codes. I just posted the code I had, and anyone with simple Swift knowledge should be able to write the Swift code :). Its all about learning after all :)

But any way here is the swift code.

```
    let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "blah blah", attributes: [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])
    label.attributedText = string
```

Comment: Your answer *may* be correct, but the question specifically asks for **Swift** code examples, not Objective-C. Please edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use attribute text. Here for swift

```
let textBgColor = UIColor.greenColor()
let attributes = [
        NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : textBgColor
]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: Constant.kDescriptionArray[0], attributes: attributes)

descriptionLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```