# Add highlight/background to only text using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I want to highlight or add a background only on a text on a label that is not center-aligned.

I already tried Attributed Strings (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38069772/676822) and using regex but didn't get near a good solution.
NSAttributedString won't work because my label is not centered and it doesn't contain line breaks. It's just a long text that takes multiple lines.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Note: It's not "Evangelizing\nDesign\nThinking" it's "Evangelizing Design Thinking"

Thanks!

Comment: make use of attributed string

Comment: @YogeshTandel Thanks. I did try it with no success. I corrected the question text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I have tried its not possible to get what you want simply with attributed text because using:

```
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Evangelizing Desing Thinking",
    attributes: [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
        .backgroundColor: UIColor.gray
    ]
)
```

Will add extray gray background at the end of each line. My previous answer was not good neither because it only adds a gray background on each word, not on spaces, and as @Alladinian noticed, ranges can be wrong in some cases.

So here is a hack you can use to achieve what you want. It uses multiple labels but it can be easily improved by putting labels in a custom view. So, in your `viewDidLoad` / `CustomView` function add:

```
    // Maximum desired width for your text
    let maxLabelWidth: CGFloat = 80
    // Font you used
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    // Your text
    let text = "Eva ngel izing Des ing a Thin king"
    // Width of a space character
    let spaceWidth = NSString(string: " ").size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]).width

    // Width of a row
    var currentRowWidth: CGFloat = 0
    // Content of a row
    var currentRow = ""
    // Previous label added (we keep it to add constraint betweeen labels)
    var prevLabel: UILabel?

    let subStrings = text.split(separator: " ")
    for subString in subStrings {
        let currentWord = String(subString)
        let nsCurrentWord = NSString(string: currentWord)
        // Width of the new word
        let currentWordWidth = nsCurrentWord.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font]).width
        // Width of the row if you add a new word
        let currentWidth = currentRow.count == 0 ? currentWordWidth : currentWordWidth + spaceWidth + currentRowWidth

        if currentWidth <= maxLabelWidth { // The word can be added in the current row
            currentRowWidth = currentWidth
            currentRow += currentRow.count == 0 ? currentWord : " " + currentWord
        } else { // Its not possible to add a new word in the current row, we create a label with the current row content
            prevLabel = generateLabel(with: currentRow,
                                      font: font,
                                      prevLabel: prevLabel)
            currentRowWidth = currentWordWidth
            currentRow = currentWord
        }
    }

    // Dont forget to add the last row
    generateLabel(with: currentRow,
                  font: font,
                  prevLabel: prevLabel)
```

Then you have to create the `generateLabel` function:

```
@discardableResult func generateLabel(with text: String,
                                      font: UIFont,
                                      prevLabel: UILabel?) -> UILabel {
    let leftPadding: CGFloat = 50 // Left padding of the label
    let topPadding: CGFloat = 100 // Top padding of (first) label

    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: leftPadding).isActive = true
    if let prevLabel = prevLabel {
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: prevLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: topPadding).isActive = true
    }
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.backgroundColor = .gray

    return label
}
```

---

**Previous answer:**

As Yogesh suggested, you can use attributed string:

```
    // Init label
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 90, height: 120))
    self.view.addSubview(label)
    label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.backgroundColor = .white

    // Create attributed text
    let text = "Evangelizing Desing Thinking"
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text,
        attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        ]
    )

    // Find ranges of each word
    let subStrings = text.split(separator: " ")
    let ranges = subStrings.map { (subString) -> Range<String.Index> in
        guard let range = text.range(of: subString) else {
            fatalError("something wrong with substring") // This case should not happen
        }
        return range
    }

    // Apply background color for each word
    ranges.forEach { (range) in
        let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: text)
        attributedText.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.gray, range: nsRange)
    }

    // Finally set attributed text
    label.attributedText = attributedText
```

Comment: This method would not work if you try to inject one-letter words or punctuation (you can try to add a single 'a' between design & thinking for example)

Comment: You are right, it does not work especially for spaces. I need to think how to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same using the first method. I tried the second method but I could not set the paddings so I switched to 1st method. I adjusted my code to macOS by changing the labels to nstextview but I do not see anything being generated. The code builds without an error. Can someone point me to the right direction.